# Longest Univalue path in BST

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to solve the problem:

Given a binary tree, find the length of the longest path where each node in the path has the same value. This path may or may not pass through the root.

Note: The length of path between two nodes is represented by the number of edges between them.

Sample inputs [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-univalue-path/)

I am getting wrong answer on a large input. My code passes 46 tests but fails after that. I don't understand where I went wrong. Could someone please help.

Here is my code:

```
 class Solution
{
      public:
        int longestPath = 0;

        int findLongestPath(TreeNode *root, int depth)
        {
                int leftDepth, rightDepth;
                leftDepth = rightDepth = 0;
                if (root->left != 0 && root->left->val == root->val)
                        leftDepth = findLongestPath(root->left, depth + 1);
                if (root->right != 0 && root->right->val == root->val)
                        rightDepth = findLongestPath(root->right, depth + 1);
                longestPath = max(longestPath, leftDepth + rightDepth);
                return max(max(leftDepth, rightDepth), depth);
        }

        void traverse(TreeNode *root)
        {
                if (root == 0)
                        return;
                findLongestPath(root, 0);
                traverse(root->left);
                traverse(root->right);
        }

        int longestUnivaluePath(TreeNode *root)
        {
                traverse(root);
                return longestPath;
        }
};
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this line `longestPath = max(longestPath, leftDepth+rightDepth);` imo this should be something like `longestPath = max(longestPath, max(1, max(leftDepth, rightDepth)));`

Comment: @Thomas It is an alternative way of writing, if(leftDepth+rightDepth > longestPath) longestPath = leftDepth+rightDepth;

Comment: please add the testCase your code is falling

Comment: @NaorShlomoTedgi The test case is thousands of lines long. I submitted it to an Online Judge that only provides me the function that I need to complete, longestUnivaluePath. It does not give how the input is processed by the main.cpp of the program it uses in the back end. What I can tell you is that my answer gives 4 when the expected output is 3. I've mentioned the path to the question on the OJ with hyperlink "here" for further reference